# Scraping from Mexico in GCP EKG?

Tags: web-scraping, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm currently utilizing Selenium in conjunction with ProxyRack on Google Cloud Plataform Kubernets Engine, but the performance is considerably sluggish. Is there a method to configure my node pool, establish a new cluster or other tools in GCP that specifically utilizes Mexican IPs?

Its related to ads scraping so localization really matters

I've come across GCP's Cluster Region feature, such as the one available for Brazil, which addresses some of my other requirements.
However, I'm in need of Mexican IPs and I'd prefer to discontinue the use of proxies due to their sluggishness and frequent complications. Any guidance on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Based from this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/infrastructure/announcing-a-new-google-cloud-region-in-mexico) There will be an upcoming new Google Cloud Region to Mexico, although upon checking this resource, it seems that it is not available yet.

My advice for this concern is to deploy your resources to the nearest region to Mexico if your target users are from Mexico. Upon checking the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/about/locations/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=japac-PH-all-en-dr-SKWS-all-all-trial-DSA-dr-1605216&utm_content=text-ad-none-none-DEV_c-CRE_651023602500-ADGP_Hybrid%20%7C%20SKWS%20-%20BRO%20%7C%20DSA%20-All%20Webpages-KWID_39700075532963485-dsa-19959388920&userloc_1011169-network_g&utm_term=KW_&gad_source=1&gclid=CjwKCAjw7-SvBhB6EiwAwYdCAaOqzdgD0-CUhrVo0bFZy4Ol0B_S0JcJ4Wa_6efQ6fzVhUvx49gQUxoCMQgQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds#regions) there is a graph that shows the current region that GCP has, and based on the graph under the region it shows that Dallas is the closest region from Mexico.

You can try this set up and test if this one will still give you a sluggish connection.